# When i am generate dynamicaly Jquery UI Slider cannot get the value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have some Jquery UI sliders with different data-id. How is it possible to detect who is the selected and return the sliders value in a span next to it and next div?
I am generate the sliders and the other elements dynamicaly:

check my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Yg85V/5/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#adding").click(function() {

var intId = $("#buildyourform div").length + 1;
var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/>");
var fName = $("<input type=\"text\" class=\"fieldname\" value=\"Enter your Facebook fan page url\" />");
var fType = $("<div id=\"slider\" data-id=\"slider" + intId + "\" style='width:250px; float:left; margin-left:10px;'></div>").slider();
var fLikes= $("<span class=\"slider" + intId + "\" style=\"width: 60px; height: 24px; float: left; margin-left: 13px; margin-top: 7px; border: 1px solid #999; color: rgb(243, 20, 145); text-align: center; font-family: serif;\" />");
var fCost = $("<div class=\"fieldname\" id=\"fcost" + intId + "\" style=\"width: 60px; height: 24px; float: left; margin-left: 6px; margin-top: 7px; border: 1px solid #999; color: rgb(243, 20, 145); text-align: center; font-family: serif;\" />");
var removeButton = $("<input type=\"button\" class=\"remove\" value=\"-\" />");
removeButton.click(function() {
$(this).parent().remove();
});
fieldWrapper.append(fName);
fieldWrapper.append(fType);
fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);
fieldWrapper.append(fLikes);
fieldWrapper.append(fCost);
$("#buildyourform").append(fieldWrapper);
});
});
```

And inside body:

```
<fieldset id="buildyourform">
<legend>Welcome! <span style="color:#F00; margin-left:13px;">My products</span></legend>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery UI Slider `change` event for getting the value of the slider as follows :

```
 $("someSelector").slider({
       change:function(event, ui) { 

             }
```

and use `ui.value` to get current slider value

And then use document traversing to set the value to the next `span` and `div` as mentioned :

```
var fType = $("<div id=\"slider\" data-id=\"slider" + intId + "\" style='width:250px; float:left; margin-left:10px;'></div>").slider({
      change:function(event, ui) { 
            //Find next span and div to the current selected slider div
            $(this).nextAll("span:first").html(ui.value);
            $(this).parent().find("div.fieldname").html(ui.value);
            }
    });
```

Hope this helps.

And here is the updated [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Yg85V/6/)